# Bootbox and JQuery Ajax - Dialogue keeps popping up

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

I am using jquery ajax to delete a record from a row of table results. All this is working....I however decided to add bootbox confirmation dialog to the mix.

The problem is that the dialog box pops up and when I click confirm, the ajax bit is done and the record is deleted from the table, however the bootbox dialogue box pops back up again (its does this 3 times) until it redirects to http://mydomain.com/undefined

My bootstrap based HTML looks like this

```
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger ajax-delete"
                            data-record-id="1"
                            data-which-table="commissions"
                            data-ajax-url="http://domain.com/delete.php">
<i class="icon-remove">
</i>
</button>
```

and the js like this

```
$(document).on("click", ".ajax-delete", function(e){

//get variables from link attributes
var id = $(this).attr("data-record-id");
var dbtable = $(this).attr("data-which-table");
var ajaxurl = $(this).attr("data-ajax-url");
var parent = $(this).parents("tr:first"); //delete the whole row <tr></tr>

e.preventDefault();

//process bootboxjs confirm alert box   
bootbox.confirm("Are you so sure?", function(result){
    //if agreed, start ajax 
    if (result) {   


        //______Ajax Bit________________________
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: 'id=' + id + '&dbtable=' + dbtable,

            //success, annimate and remove row
            success: function(){
                parent.slideUp(300, function(){
                    parent.remove();
                });
            }

            //todo fail output
        });
    }                 

});
});
```

Comment: Try by replacing button tag to anchor.
also, may replace code as 
    $(".ajax-delete").click(function(e){
       //write code here
    });

Comment: @kd12, this did not work